# MobX: Пример регистрации пользователя

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Приведите, пожалуйста, пример отправки данных на сервер из формы с помощью Rect + MobX.
Изучаю MobX для управления состоянием React приложения и необходим пример для лучшего понимая архитектуры.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Вот эта статья ответила мне на мой вопрос: https://medium.com/@KozhukharenkoN/react-form-validation-with-mobx-8ce00233ae27